# kubernetes cache clear and handling

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am using Kubernetes with Helm 3.8.0, with windows docker desktop configured on WSL2.

Sometime, after running: `helm install`, and retrieve a container, the container that is created behind sense, is an old container that created before (even after restarting the computer).

i.e: Now the yaml is declared with password: 12345, and database: test. before I tried to run the container yaml with password: 11111, and database: my_database.

Now when I do `helm install mychart ./mychart --namespace test-chart --create-namespace` for the current folder chart, the container is running with password: 11111 and database: my_datatbase, instead of the new parameters provided. There is no current yaml code with the old password, so I don't understand why the docker is run with the old one.

I did several actions, such as docker system prune, restarting Windows Docker Desktop, but still I get the old container, that cannot be seen, even in Windows Docker Desktop, I have checked the option in: Settings -> Kubernetes -> Show System Containers -> Show system containers.

After some investigations, I realized that that **may be** because of Kubernetes has it's own garbage collection handling of containers, and that is why I may refer to old container, even I didn't mean to.

In my case, I am creating a job template (I didn't put any line that reference this job in the _helpers.tpl file - I never changed that file, and I don't know whether that may cause a problem).

Here is my job template:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: {{ include "myChart.fullname" . }}-migration
  labels:
    name: {{ include "myChart.fullname" . }}-migration
  annotations:
    "helm.sh/hook": pre-install,pre-upgrade
    "helm.sh/hook-weight": "-300"
    "helm.sh/hook-delete-policy": before-hook-creation      
spec:
  parallelism: 1 
  completions: 1
  backoffLimit: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: {{ template "myChart.name" . }}
        release: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
    spec:
      initContainers:
        - name: wait-mysql
          image: {{ .Values.mysql.image }}
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          env:
          - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
            value: "12345"
          - name: MYSQL_DATABASE
            value: test
          command:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - |
              service mysql start &
              until mysql -uroot -p12345 -e 'show databases'; do
                echo `date +%H:%M:%S`' - Waiting for mysql...'
                sleep 5
              done
      containers:
        - name: migration
          image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag | default .Chart.AppVersion }}"
          command: {{- toYaml .Values.image.entrypoint | nindent 12 }}
          args: {{- toYaml .Values.image.cmd | nindent 12}}
      restartPolicy: Never
```

In the job - there is a database, which is first created, and after that it has data that is populated with code.

Also, are the annotations (hooks) are necessary?

After running `helm install myChart ./myChart --namespace my-namespace --create-namespace`, I realized that I am using very old container, which I don't really need.

I didn't understand if I write the meta data, as the following example (in: [Garbage Collection](https://unofficial-kubernetes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/concepts/workloads/controllers/garbage-collection/)) really help, and what to put in uid, whether I don't know it, or don't have it.

```
 metadata:
  ...
  ownerReferences:
  - apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
    controller: true
    blockOwnerDeletion: true
    kind: ReplicaSet
    name: my-repset
    uid: d9607e19-f88f-11e6-a518-42010a800195
```

Sometimes I really want to reference existing pod (or container) from several templates (use the same container, which is not stateless, such as database container - one template for the pod and the other for the job) - How can I do that, also?

Is there any command (in command line, or a kind of method) that clear all the cached in Garbage Collection, or not use Garbage Collection at all? (What are the main benefits for the GC of Kubernetes?)

Comment: When you say "container", do you mean "image", or the database data, or something else?  How can you tell it's old?

Comment: Eitan, it's not very clear what you want to do. Please, check your question for where pod/container/image are meant to be. How do you know it's old (what command do you run to check it)?

Comment: For clarification - I meant container.
There is container with parameters
The container is too old. (Several days). No matter how much, because after running `helm install`, I see that it a new pod is created, and a new container is created (docker ps). When I inpect the new running docker, I see that it runs not with the new parameters, but with the same old parameters as before.

Comment: i.e: I now I trying running container with password: 12345, and database: test, before I tried to run the container with password: 11111, and database: my_database. Now when I do helm install for the folder, the container is running with password: 11111 and database: my_datatbase, instead of the new parameters provided. There is no current yaml code with the old password, so I don't understand why the docker is run with the old one.

Comment: Do you delete old k8s jobs before running 'helm install`? Do you use the same helm install name every time? Try to clean the helm cache before running 'helm install' again. To clean the cache run 'rm -rf ~/.cache/helm/archive/*' and 'rm -rf ~/.cache/helm/repository/*'.

Comment: there is no folder ~/.cache/helm/archive/. Only ~/.cache/helm/repository/ folder.
Nonetheless, I delete the ~/.cache/helm/repository/ folder. Still - same problem.

Comment: What if you you specify a new helm install name? The problem is still there?